# Is there any way to run Python model in background?

Tags: java, python, spring, jython, python-multithreading

I have a web-app project that's using Java as the base code. 
Then there is a need to use one of the Python model that been trained to do some prediction. 
I'm able to load the full script of Python and run it whenever needed, but the problem is the loading time. 
Whenever the Python script being called, it will need to reload the whole script including the model before doing the prediction.
Say, the whole script when do fresh run will takes up 30s
So, when I do 4 predictions through the web-app will +- taking up 4 x 30s = 120s. Or the fastest if in 1 run to do 4 predictions all together will be +- 40s 
Not to mention when the page reloaded, it will need to do another fresh start
Which the waiting time is too long to wait.

So, I'm thinking is there any way for me to load the model only once at the very first time, then the rest will be just calling the prediction function?
Maybe like caching Python model in the background then to use the model (variable) in the next run?

Comment: You should probably run a python process as a separate service, perhaps a simple flask endpoint and then it can just be a simple server.

Answer (score 0):

To initialize the load model only once, you need to use **singleton design pattern** in java. Once the model class initializes the instance is created. You can use this instance whenever required.

```
public class LoadSingletonModel {

    private static LoadSingletonModel instance;

    private LoadSingletonModel(){}

    public static synchronized LoadSingletonModel getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new LoadSingletonModel();
        }
        return instance;
    }

}
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: You don't *need* a singlton for this, and that doesn't really address the OPs problem at all to begin with.